# Convert Comma-Separated Strings to multiple String

Tags: vb.net

I know this has been answered many times , but I was wondering if someone could teach me the simplest approach to splitting a string (comma separated) i.e string  number=1,2,3,4,5 ,7,8,9,10

such that

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

after splitting I want to insert that into Database table as separate row(10 rows).I want to ask how I will do that?whether I have to place them into 10 variables?Just getting a bit confused on the iteration over the string!

Comment: In which language? You tagged 3.

Comment: i am working in vb.net

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim LineOfText As String = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" 
Dim i As Integer
Dim aryTextFile() As String

aryTextFile = LineOfText.Split( "," )

For i = 0 To UBound(aryTextFile)

MsgBox( aryTextFile(i) )

Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its 5 months old but just in case you still need the answer:

```
dim stringNumber as string = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10"

Dim stringSpiltArray as string()
If Not stringNumber Is Nothing And stringNumber.Length <> 0 Then 
   stringSpiltArray = stringNumber.Split(',')
End If

For Each str As String In stringSpiltArray 
  'insert into db
Next
```

Use `split()` to split up your string and store the separated values in an `array`.

Then use a `for each` loop to each item in the array.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim substr As String() = txtString.Text.Split(", ")

For Each strnumber As Integer In substr
     txtoutput.Text=strnumber & vbNewLine
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`string.Split(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method to store all results into an `string array`

All of your Choosen languages contains such methods

Answer (score 0):

Using the `String.split()` will return an array of strings .

Comment: i have break down the string as
 Dim words() As String = string.Split(",")

        ' Use For Each loop over words and display them
        Dim word As String
        For Each word In words
            Response.Write(word)
        Next

now how i have split string into an array..but how to insert it as separate row

Comment: Instead of printing to screen in your loop insert into database

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the comma separated string to the db and then split there only. If using sql then you can use the following function

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSplit(
    @sInputList VARCHAR(8000) -- List of delimited items
  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ',' -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(8000)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT
  @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
 END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
END
GO
```

Comment: don't do it if you can avoid it.  SQL servers are better at set operations not iterative  loops

Comment: [VB.Net....](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18045502/convert-comma-separated-strings-to-multiple-string#comment26400678_18045502)

Answer (score 0):

The below code splits string on the basis of delimiter. You may set StringSplitOptions to either ignore empty entries or add the empty entries to the string array as well.

```
//C#
String sentence = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9";
String[] delim = {","};
String[] words = sentence.Split(delim,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries );
```

The below code is implemented in C++. It takes a line as input from user and uses strtok to split string based on the delimiters.

```
//C++
string line;
char* word;
getline(cin,line);
word = strtok(const_cast<char*>(line.c_str())," ");
while(word)
{
   //input this word in container of your choice
   word = strtok(NULL," ");
}
```

Comment: Whats with the C# and C++ it's a VB.Net question